# android save contacts and call them

Tags: android, call, contacts

i am programming a little bit android and i have a problem with adding and calling contacts.

my idea was to add two contacts and when the call-button was pressed the user can decide which one he wants to call.. and my two problems are, that on my AVD the code is working until i have to call somebody. so i can choose 2 contacts and these contacts are safed... on the phone of my friend i cant even choose contacts.. the programm just says: "The Application Contacts_SPrefs stopped working"...

well i think there is a problem in my code.. but i dont know where it is and how i could fix it, because in my previous version the code works...

So in this part of the app you can add 2 contacts and choose the button call which opens the other intent which is described below

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.contact_sprefs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String contact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // this opens the activity. note the  Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    // and the intent.setType
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.bro1)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            //-------- > this thing here opens the contacts view < ------
            //later its waiting until the user clicks on a number of his contacts
            contact = "Brah1";
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                
        }
    });

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.bro2)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            contact = "Brah2";
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.call)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OpenMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });        
}

//doing random sh*t which i dont know whaat happens
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        //after he clicked a number its getting to this point
        //in the uri it saves some number and all this things where the contact is
        //so this is for the location
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            //get more data
            //in this cursor all the values of the contacts are going to be safed
            //c is for the contact
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                //here all datas from the contact are going to be safed in c
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE  },
                        null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    //c is the phone number in very special code types and stuff like that
                    //in c is everything from the contact saved
                    //now c is going to be converted into a string -> everything that stays is the phone number
                    String number = c.getString(0);
                    //get the type... somehow
                    int type = c.getInt(1);

                    showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                    save(contact, number);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved Nr : " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
}

public void save(String type, String number) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putString(type, number);
    edit.commit();
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

so.. as you can see.. i dont know really much about the topic Intent and its specifications.. anyway... heres the second part of the app, in which the call-command is.. and this command doesent work either...

**OpenMenu**

```
       package com.example.contact_sprefs;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class OpenMenu extends Activity {

        private String nr;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.open_menu);

            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.bro1)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    nr = load("Brah1", nr);
                    String uri = "tel:" + nr.trim() ;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(intent);  
                }
            });

            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.bro2)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    nr = load("Brah2", nr);
                    String uri = "tel:" + nr.trim() ;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
     }

        public void showSelectedNumber(String number) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Took Nr : " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
        }

        public String load(String brahNr, String number) {
            String sharedNumber;
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            sharedNumber = sp.getString(brahNr, number);

            return sharedNumber;
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.get

ItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }    
}
```

....well... this is a lot of code(for me).. and i thank everybody who helps me :)

---

edited lateron

i just forgot the permissions... so this is also needed

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

vZ

Comment: Hey, you need to learn how to use `LogCat`. Plug your friend's phone in, turn on USB Debugging mode and check the LogCat for errors. Helping you will be a lot easier then.

Comment: omg please kill me guys... i forgott the 2 permissions... omg i am so retarded... faq...

Comment: Post an answer for the solution and accept it, to help other people  in need.